# FileZilla: FATAL ERROR: Signature from server's host key is invalid

Tags: ftp, sftp, scp, filezilla

I'm transferring a big file with sFTP from local to a webhosting. After 9mins30sec I've always this error. Then FileZilla reconnects and continue the upload from where it was stopped. Is it a timeout from the hosting? If the file stops transferring, then start again, then stops, then starts again, will it be transferred with success and without corruptions?

```
Error:  FATAL ERROR: Signature from server's host key is invalid
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 2.139.045.888 bytes in 569 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i had the same issue with FileZilla (3.60.2) and ProFTPD (1.3.7a)? After transfering 2Gb i got:

```
Error:  FATAL ERROR: Signature from server's host key is invalid
```

I think it's FileZilla that tries to rekey after 2Gb but failes with the default key exchange algorithm (curve25519-sha256@libssh.org).

I changed the key exchange algorithm from curve25519-sha256@libssh.org to ecdh-sha2-nistp521 and it worked.

In proftpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
  SFTPEngine on
  ...
  SFTPKeyExchanges ecdh-sha2-nistp521
</IfModule>
```

For more info: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html#SFTPKeyExchanges

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).